# How to check two unordered_map instances for equality in gcc 4.4?

Tags: c++, c++11

It looks like the STL in gcc 4.4 doesn't include operator== for unordered_map.  (I'm forced to support RHEL6, and I'm using the intel compiler to do it, but it uses GCC's STL).  Absent that definition, how can I reliably (and quickly) compare two unordered_map instances for equality?

Comment: Looks like you have to iterate over one and do lookup on another

Comment: And you would want to read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_cmp before implementing it. It's not quite as easy as it looks.

Comment: @NeilButterworth That's a very interesting read.  Let's assume for a moment that the "naive" approach returns true iff each member of `lhs` is in `rhs` and vice versa, noting that member in this context means `pair<key, value>`.  Does this definition have the same semantic meaning as the combination of the two bullet items on your linked page, and if not, what might be an example of two maps that disagree on their equality when compared with criteria I've stated and `unordered_map::operator==`.

Comment: It's really a nuisance that your compiler does not support the standard. Is there no way to use a more recent version?

Comment: @Walter pretty sure gcc 4.4 [doesn't fully support C++11](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) so its not surprising it'd have an incomplete `std::unordered_map` implementation

Comment: @Walter sadly no, I've tried my best.  I've gotten to where I don't have to support gcc 4.4 itself, but Intel uses the gcc STL, so I can't avoid it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm not entirely sure what that's saying, how can you have multiple values that have an equal key?

Comment: Sean McAllister: I have seen the page Neil quotes and  agree with you and disagree with the page. With unordered_map, it is enough to iterate through the keys, see if the other key exists in the other containerr and I ssume the values are the same. If it was  unordered_multimap, for each key is the number of each had to be the same and the values are a permutation of each other

Comment: @SJHowe There is indeed something wrong in that cppreference page (a rarity): since `unordered_map` stores unique keys, there is no range of equivalent keys. The page looks like it should be for `unordered_multimap`.

Comment: @SJHowe and Walter, unordered_map does indeed have an equal_range function though.  I think perhaps you can have keys that compare equal and hash differently?

Comment: Sean McAllister: Yes I think that is possible. Your 2 containers could be different sizes before elements being erased and bring them down to the same size before a compare. Therefore hash buckets could be different. But they should be comparable for equality of keys.